# How to mock class instead of object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How can I mock the following?

```
import os
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

class A:
    VAR_A = os.environ.get("ABC")

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
       return cls.VAR_A

@patch.dict(os.environ, {'ABC': 'abc'})
class Test_A(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertEqual(A.foo(), 'abc')
```

This `VAR_A` is not getting mocked. `AssertionError: None != 'abc'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to test your `foo()` function. Instead of trying to change environment variable before `class` object definition try to mock already existing `class`'s attribute. As class object is created before your test is run and `VAR_A` attribute is already initialized.

```
import os
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch

class A:
    VAR_A = os.environ.get("ABC")

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
       return cls.VAR_A

@patch.object(A, 'VAR_A', 'abc')
class Test_A(TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        self.assertEqual(A.foo(), 'abc')
```